# Create folder with Date and Userprofile name

Tags: windows, date, batch-file

Im trying to make a Bat file that creates a folder at a certain place with the Date in its name and the Name of the user.

Like:

> "21-3-2016 Thomas"

I found something with the date but that also places the name of the day in front of it and thats what i am trying to get rid off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
@echo off
FOR /f %%a in ('WMIC OS GET LocalDateTime ^| find "."') DO set DTS=%%a
set "FolderName=%DTS:~6,2%-%DTS:~4,2%-%DTS:~0,4% %username%"
mkdir "%FolderName%"
```

Comment: That is exactly what i wanted! Thank you very much!